# Laravel Saving data

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

In my Laravel project I use this code into controller method to save data:

```
    $countCourseTeacher++;
    $routine->p1=Input::get('course_teacher' . $countCourseTeacher); 
    $routine->p2=Input::get('course_teacher' . $countCourseTeacher); 
    $routine->p3=Input::get('course_teacher' . $countCourseTeacher);
```

But I want to use  `$routine->p$i` into a for loop Like

```
for ($i=1; $i <=6; $i++) {
               $countCourseTeacher++;
               $routine->p$i=Input::get('course_teacher' . $countCourseTeacher);
               }
```

When I use `$routine->p$i`
instead of using 
`$routine->p1 , $routine->p2, $routine->p3`..... 
It gives error. Is there any way to do this into a forloop using `p$i`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Way I find My answer myself. I use thos code below

```
for ($j=1; $j <=6; $j++) {
       $routine=new RoutineCreate;
       $routine->configuration_id=$idcnfg; 
       $routine->day=Input::get('day' . $j);
       for ($i=1; $i <=10; $i++) {
        $pi="p" . $i;
       $countCourseTeacher++;

       $routine->$pi=Input::get('course_teacher' . $countCourseTeacher);
       }
       $routine->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal behaviour in PHP. You can use interpolation. If you want to use interpolation for object properties/methods, use brackets around the string. Here are a quick example:

```
for ($i=1; $i <=6; $i++) {
    $countCourseTeacher++;
    $routine->{"p$i"} = Input::get('course_teacher'.$countCourseTeacher);
}
```